# Effect of bad antenna design on chip behaviour

Tags: antenna, wifi, impedance-matching, firmware

I have designed a PCB for TI's cc3200 using recommended design specifications. The chip performs correctly when i use functionalities like GPIO read/ write, UART communication, but as soon as i use any WiFi functionality the chips goes into series of restarts from the point where WiFi function is called. I am wondering can this be hardware issue, like antenna not properly matched? Though the only change i have from antenna reference design is that the clearance between ground and antenna trace is 18 mil in reference design and 10mil in my design.

Comment: I'll just say that your antenna will certainly work differently.  I imagine you used different material (PCB) as well?

Comment: Can you post the schematic? Can you put a meter or scope on the power rails? This sounds like classic browning out of power rails.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are not providing enough current to the device. when the WiFi module start transmission it consumes x100mA in the range of 300-450mA. you should make sure to provide enough juice.
For further support you can find TI representative in here:https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/simplelink_wifi_cc31xx_cc32xx/f/968

I hope my answer will help,
@NirNitzani

Comment: Brown out was the first thing i suspected. I measured the voltage on power rail, it was pretty stable between 3.23 to 3.27V and current consumption was between 41-42mA. I measured voltage and current using a digital multimeter, i am not sure if multimeter is fast enough to see voltage drop which might be happening for really small time as the module restarts in loop. About e2e the response is really slow. I posted question 3 days back and have not received any response yet.

Comment: Also i supplied the module using a supply rated 1A, so not enough juice should not be an issue. I used the same PCB material as suggested by TI.